# how can do left join with lambda expression in c# using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to do left join with lambda expression. But I don't know how can I do that. I have tried many LINQ queries, but haven't gotten proper query. I am a new to the Entity Framework. So any one who know how I can do that, please let me know.

Here below i have try this query :

```
var query = UsersContext.Users.OrderBy(a => a.Email).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
var result = (from u in db.Notification
              join c in query on u.id equals c.Id into j1
              from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { u, j2 }).OrderByDescending(a => a.u.datetime).Take(3).ToList();
```

This is my query. I want to left it join with notification table and get only the last 3 notifications.

Comment: EF is an ORM. LINQ is a query language on top of the ORM, *not* a SQL replacement. You should define navigation properties and relations on the entities, *NOT* try to join them as if they were tables. Your `User` class should have a `Notifications` collection property that you can use to retrieve notifications.

Comment: can you please give me a hint, bcs i m new for entity framework

Comment: Are `UsersContext` and `db` different `DbContext`s?

Comment: You cannot join with your query because you materialized it with `ToList`. You cannot join database table with in-memory list.

Comment: yes it's different DbContext i have used membership login so UsersContext is use for the users data getting

Comment: guys i have suffering for on issue please let me know any propare solution.

Comment: The problem is EF does not support `join`s to in memory collections, so we need to seeks for another solution. Can you show the `Notification` class? Also the desired result - something like list containing user and list of the last 3 notifications for that user?

Comment: Now, if I'm following that query right, it should give you the last three notifications (overall)  -- plus the User information,  **only if** that user happens to be on a  selected page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = UsersContext.Users.Blah().Blah().ToList();
 // It's a non-complete List of Users....  (all we care about)

 var ids = query.Select(u=>u.Id).ToArray();
 // get an array of needed Users.

var notes = (from u in db.Notification
              where ids.Contains(u.id)
              select u).ToList(); 

var results = from u in notes
          join c in query on u.id equals c.Id into j1
          from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { u, j2 }).OrderByDescending(a => a.u.datetime).Take(3).ToList();
```